# How do I write this loop as a single line?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, for-loop, dataset

I don't know this is possible or not but let me ask you. How do I write the below loop in a shorter way using, for example, LINQ?

```
DataSet dsAllMonsters 
List<string> lstAllMonsters

for (int i = 0; i < dsAllMonsters.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    lstAllMonsters.Add(dsAllMonsters.Tables[0].Rows[i]["pokemonId"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be shortened. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Please don't imply questions. =)

Comment: Do you have a shortage of newline characters in your workplace? :-) You could lose the braces, you could even put the `for` and `add` on a single line but I need to ask why. There's nothing intrinsically unreadable about a short `for` statement like that.

Comment: @paxdiablo the thing is about writing code in the most effective way. the way i showed here is the lame way i have been using all the time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it could.

```
lstAllMonsters = dsAllMonsters.Tables[0].Rows
   .Cast<DataRow>()
   .Select(r => r["pokemonId"].ToString())
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done in one line:

```
lstAllMonsters = dsAllMonsters.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["pokemonId"].ToString()).ToList();
```

But sometimes two lines are better than one. I think you will find this more readable:

```
var rows = dsAllMonsters.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
lstAllMonsters = rows.Select(row => row["pokemonId"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: i think you have to cast the row items otherwise the linq operators won't light up.

Comment: anything that isn't generic only a few linq operations work on it.

Comment: this linQ is awesome. i really need to master it thank you :)

Comment: This won't work: 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @KarelFrajtak: Have you seen the update where I added the call to `Cast`?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of achieving it in one line.

```
dsAllMonsters.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach((DataRow a) => lstAllMonsters.Add(a["pokemonId"].ToString()));
```

Comment: that enumerates it multiple times.